# How to improve this code?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

The aim of my work is to find a value for the complex constant $\omega$. In order to do that I solve the below system of differential equations with a manual shooting method: I first solve the system in the range $(0.34,0.5)$ with the initial condition that the functions are zero at $0.34$ and leaving the derivative as parameters; I solve analogously the problem in the range $(0.5,0.999)$ with the final condition that the function vanishes at $0.999$ and leaving again the derivatives as parameters; finally I use `FindRoot` to fix the value of the parameters.

The code works...kinda. It seems that it does not explore the parameter space and for some parameters it gives as output the input value. As can be seen in the below plots the results is ridiculously wrong. How can I improve the code? I have already tried increasing `WorkingPrecision` and such and also to set the `MaxIteration` option to higher values, but it only made the code slower.

Her the code. First some definition of functions

```
M = 1;
g = 0;
l = 2;
m[r_] = (M r^3)/(r^3 + 2 M g^2);
a1[r_] = -((r - 2 m[r])^2/r^4);
a2[r_] = (
  2 (2 m[r]^2 - 2 m[r] r + r^2) (3 m[r] - r (1 - m'[r])))/((2 m[r] - 
     r) r^5);
a3[r_] = -1/((2 m[r] - r) r^6) (8 m[r]^3 + 
      2 m[r]^2 r (-6 + l + l^2 - 4 m'[r]) - 
      2 m[r] r^2 (-6 + l + l^2 - 4 m'[r]) + 
      r^2 (-4 + l + l^2 - 4 m'[r]));
a4[r_] = 1/(r - 2 m[r])^2;
b1[r_] = (4 m[r] (r - m[r]))/((2 m[r] - r) r^2);
b2[r_] = 2/(
   r^3 (r - 2 m[r])^2) (-4 m[r]^3 + r^3 - 
     m[r] r^2 (4 + l + l^2 - 4 m'[r] + 
        m[r]^2 r (6 + l + l^2 - 4 m'[r])));
c1[r_] = (r - 2 m[r])/r;
c2[r_] = -((4 (-3 m[r] + r + r m'[r]))/r^2);
c3[r_] = -2 (10 m[r] + r (-3 - 4 m'[r] + r m''[r]))/r^3;
c4[r_] = -(r/(2 m[r] - r));
d1[r_] = -r^2;
d2[r_] = 2 (m[r] - r m'[r])/(2 m[r] - r);
d3[r_] = r^4/(r - 2 m[r])^2;
a1t[t_] = a1[(t + 1)/(1 - t)] 1/2 (t - 1)^3;
a2t[t_] = a2[(t + 1)/(1 - t)] 1/2 (t - 1)^2;
a3t[t_] = a3[(t + 1)/(1 - t)];
a4t[t_] = a4[(t + 1)/(1 - t)];
b1t[t_] = b1[(t + 1)/(1 - t)] 1/2 (t - 1)^2;
b2t[t_] = b2[(t + 1)/(1 - t)];
c1t[t_] = c1[(t + 1)/(1 - t)] 1/2 (t - 1)^3;
c2t[t_] = c2[(t + 1)/(1 - t)] 1/2 (t - 1)^2;
c3t[t_] = c3[(t + 1)/(1 - t)];
c4t[t_] = c4[(t + 1)/(1 - t)];
d1t[t_] = d1[(t + 1)/(1 - t)] 1/2 (t - 1)^3;
d2t[t_] = d2[(t + 1)/(1 - t)] 1/2 (t - 1)^2;
d3t[t_] = d3[(t + 1)/(1 - t)];
```

Here the differential equations and the solution with `ParametricNDSolveValue`

```
s1 = ParametricNDSolveValue[{a1t[t] h22''[t] + a2t[t] h22'[t] + 
     a3t[t] h22[t] - \[Omega]^2 a4t[t] h22[t] + b1t[t] h00'[t] + 
     b2t[t] h00[t] == 0, 
   c1t[t] h22''[t] + c2t[t] h22'[t] + 
     c3t[t] h22[t] - \[Omega]^2 c4t[t] h22[t] + d1t[t] h00''[t] + 
     d2t[t] h00'[t] - \[Omega]^2 d3t[t] h00[t] == 0, h22[34/100] == 0,
    h22'[34/100] == b, h00[34/100] == 0, h00'[34/100] == c}, {h22, 
   h00}, {t, 34/100, 1/2}, {b, c, \[Omega]}, 
  Method -> {Automatic(*,"SymbolicProcessing"\[Rule]0*)}]
s2 = ParametricNDSolveValue[{a1t[t] h22''[t] + a2t[t] h22'[t] + 
     a3t[t] h22[t] - \[Omega]^2 a4t[t] h22[t] + b1t[t] h00'[t] + 
     b2t[t] h00[t] == 0, 
   c1t[t] h22''[t] + c2t[t] h22'[t] + 
     c3t[t] h22[t] - \[Omega]^2 c4t[t] h22[t] + d1t[t] h00''[t] + 
     d2t[t] h00'[t] - \[Omega]^2 d3t[t] h00[t] == 0, 
   h22[999/1000] == 0, h22'[999/1000] == b, h00[999/1000] == 0, 
   h00'[999/1000] == c}, {h22, h00}, {t, 1/2, 999/1000}, {b, 
   c, \[Omega]}, 
  Method -> {Automatic(*,"SymbolicProcessing"\[Rule]0*)}]
```

The result of the above code is substituted in the following functions:

```
H221[\[Omega]_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ][t_] := 
  Through[s1[b, c,\[Omega]][t]][[1]];
H001[\[Omega]_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ][t_] := 
  Through[s1[b, c,\[Omega]][t]][[2]];

H222[\[Omega]_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ][t_] := 
  Through[s2[b, c,\[Omega]][t]][[1]];
H002[\[Omega]_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ][t_] := 
  Through[s2[b, c,\[Omega]][t]][[2]];
```

And finally the root search:

```
sol = FindRoot[{H221[\[Omega], b, c][1/2] == 
    H222[\[Omega], e, f][1/2], 
   Derivative[1][H221[\[Omega], b, c]][1/2] == 
    Derivative[1][H222[\[Omega], e, f]][1/2], 
   H001[\[Omega], b, c][1/2] == H002[\[Omega], e, f][1/2], 
   Derivative[1][H001[\[Omega], b, c]][1/2] == 
    Derivative[1][H002[\[Omega], e, f]][1/2], 
   Derivative[2][H001[\[Omega], b, c]][1/2] == 
    Derivative[2][H002[\[Omega], e, f]][1/2]}, {{\[Omega], 
    0.4571 - 0.0951 I, 0.45 - 0.09 I}, {b, -0.1 + 0.01 I, 0.02}, {c, 
    0.1 - I, 0.02}, {e, 0.1 + 0.1 I, 0.02}, {f, 0.1 + 0.1 I, 0.02}}, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 40, AccuracyGoal -> 40, Method -> "Secant", 
  MaxIterations -> 1000]
```

Here are two plots of the resulting functions:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Equations in `s1, s2` look identical.  Why don't you solve problem in one step on  `{t, 34/100, 999/1000}`?

Comment: Because I didn't know how to fix $\omega$ otherwise: using the shooting method I can match the values of the functions and their derivatives fixing the 5 parameters ($\omega$ and the 4 derivatives at the extrema) in my code. In order to use the shooting method I solve the same system of equations in two separated ranges and then match the solutions as said above. @AlexTrounev

Comment: There are typos in your code. In equations `s1, s2` you use order like this `{b, 
   c, \[Omega]}`, and then change it to `s1[\[Omega], b, c][t]] , s2[\[Omega], b, c][t]]` in definitions of `H221[\[Omega]_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ][t_], ...`

Comment: @AlexTrounev Indeed....Thanks for spotting that.  I have changed the order of the parameters, but the code still gives functions orders of magnitude a part.

Comment: Both equations and bc are homogeneous, therefore there is solution `h00=h22=0`. So we are looking for some eigenvalues $\omega$ to get nonzero solution. Is it correct?

Comment: @AlexTrounev yes it is correct

Comment: We need some additional constrains to get solution, like we did for Schrodinger.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Which kind of constraints?

Comment: In a case of physical problem we can suggest for instance that `Max[{Norm[h00],Norm[h22]}]<L<Infinity` and then use it to normalize eigenfunctions.